# (Newbie) MySQL View

Tags: mysql, join, view

I'm new to SQL and probably going about this the wrong way but could you help?

I need to create a VIEW in MySQL but I can't figure out how to combine these two SQL statements, as VIEWs do not accept multiple SELECTS or Variables.

NB: the second statement works perfectly when replacing the @numberOfGames var with the correct number (manually calculated).

#### First statement - to return the total number of games for year:

```
SELECT COUNT( id ) INTO @numberOfGames FROM tblgames WHERE gdate LIKE '2014%';
```

#### Second statement - to create VIEW data:

```
SELECT
p.player AS player,
COUNT( c.gid ) AS gameCount,
SUM( c.cash ) AS cash,
ROUND( AVG( c.cash ), 2 ) AS avg,
SUM( ( CASE WHEN ( c.wotn > 0 ) THEN c.wotn ELSE 0 END ) ) AS wotn,
SUM( ( CASE WHEN ( c.cash > 0 ) THEN c.cash ELSE 0 END ) ) AS cashWon,
SUM( ( CASE WHEN ( c.cash < 0 ) THEN c.cash ELSE 0 END ) ) AS cashLost,
ROUND( AVG( ( CASE WHEN ( c.cash >= 0 ) THEN c.cash END ) ),2 ) AS avgWin,
ROUND( AVG( ( CASE WHEN ( c.cash < 0 ) THEN c.cash END ) ),2 ) AS avgLoss,
IF(
( ( COUNT( c.pid ) > ( @numberOfGames / 3 ) ) AND ( COUNT( c.pid ) > 2 ) ),
ROUND( ( ( AVG( c.cash ) * 10 ) + 200 ), 2 ),
ROUND( AVG( c.cash ), 2 )
) AS sortingPoints
FROM tblplayers p
LEFT JOIN tblcash c ON p.id = c.pid
LEFT JOIN tblgames g ON g.id = c.gid
WHERE c.cash IS NOT NULL AND g.gdate LIKE '2014%'
GROUP BY c.pid
ORDER BY sortingPoints DESC;
```

I'm using the @numberOfGames vars for a simple maths equation that checks it a player has played more than a third of the total games in the year.

I hope someone can help point me it the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the point of what a view does.
You can't save multiple statements in one view.  It's like trying to save two tables in one table.  It's not possible.

What you need to do is, run your first Select, exactly as you have it.  Save it as a view.  Then you can use that result set as if it were any other live table, and join it to other tables in subsequent Select statements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply durbnpoisn. I do realise that I cannot use multiple statements in a view. The reason I have shown the first statement is, it returns the total number of games for 2014 and this is the figure I need to use within the second statement @numberOfGames. I can't use COUNT(g.id) within the second statement as it is GROUPED BY c.pid - which returns the number of games the player has totalled, not the actual total games played. Hope this clears up any confusion and hope you/someone can help.